# I need drivers for nvidia geforce gtx 745. Card doesn't work correctly

Tags: nvidia, dell

I have a Dell xps 8700 intel i7, NVIDIA Geforce GTX 745 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I can not install the appropriate driver for it.

I tried to do is something like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia *; sudo apt-get install nvidia-319-updates-dev
```

But I can not finish what I have in this process because the mode switch the ctrl + alt + f1. However this is impossible, because the graphics mode would have to act without the driver. It does not work (not even screen is displayed for the radio boxes ubuntu during startup and log off the system).

If I install this driver and later do:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

and nastepniesh /NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.run (value not remember exactly who more or less) on to install  it the screen resolution is 1024x768 and still should have 1680x1050 and it can not even change August in x-nvidia.

I know that Ubuntu is najelpszym and najpolularniejszym system and therefore has the largest base of drivers, but this August steel teeth full-fledged system must have known drivers feed of you could use it fully, so please help get it to work all on tip top and full graphics with hardware acceleration on this card and full resolution 1680x1050 :)

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday, I found a solution.

My steps:

1. Open terminal CTRL+ALT+T
2. Go to Downloads (or Pobrane if you are from Poland) directory and download installation script using below commands:

   ```
   $ cd ~/Downloads

   $ wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/346.35/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.35.run
   ```
3. Remove installed nvidia drivers

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get purge nvidia*;
   ```
4. Reboot
5. After rebooting, switch to console mode using CTRL+ALT+F1, and login
6. Stop graphic session using (I use lightdm) one of this:

   ```
   $ sudo service lightdm stop ## For the default LightDM

   $ sudo service gdm stop ## For the Gnome GDM

   $ sudo service mdm stop ## For the Linux Mint default MDM
   ```
7. Give executable rights and run installation script

   ```
   $ chmod +x ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-*.run && sudo sh ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-*.run
   ```
8. After that, reboot your os.

If this steps don't work for you, uninstall nvidia driver using command:

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-*.run --uninstall
```

I use [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-nvidia-driver-331-67-ubuntu1404/) tips.

After reboot works for me, and detects my two monitors.

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.